# why do i use NSURLconnection over loadRequest in webview class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't seem to understand what is the situation where you choose **NSURLconnection** over **loadRequest**in **webview** class..

```
   self.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.URLField text]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

And,

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]
```

what i found is that NSURLconnection is not often used with webview to display content..

could anyone explain some basic concept of this ..?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` is not used in conjunction with web views. It is used for stand-alone requests to the server (ex: hit a rest api, download some data, etc...), and it simply returns data (it does nothing to attempt to display it).

`UIWebView` is used for loading and *displaying* a web page. A web view uses an `NSURLRequest` to know which url to hit when it is trying to load a web page.
`UIWebView` may use `NSURLConnection` behind the scenes as the means of fetching and loading a web page, but you should not use them together.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic explanation is use NSURLConnection when working with webservice API, sending reqests to webserver etc. and use webview when you want to display webpages.